# Notification alerts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notifications

I need to setup notification alerts for my website. I'm using this simple [notification script](https://github.com/msroot/Notify.js/). I have test it on my website like this.

```
<div id="notifications">
 <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <a class="button close" style="padding-left: 10px;" href="#">×</a>
  <i class="fa fa-info-circle "></i>
  Thanks
 </div>
</div>
```

**Styles**

```
#notifications {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

**Script**

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
   Notify = function(text, callback, close_callback, style) {

  var time = '10000';
  var $container = $('#notifications');
  var icon = '<i class="fa fa-info-circle "></i>';

  if (typeof style == 'undefined' ) style = 'warning'

  var html = $('<div class="alert alert-' + style + '  hide">' + icon +  " " + text + '</div>');

  $('<a>',{
    text: '×',
    class: 'button close',
    style: 'padding-left: 10px;',
    href: '#',
    click: function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      close_callback && close_callback()
      remove_notice()
    }
  }).prependTo(html)

  $container.prepend(html)
  html.removeClass('hide').hide().fadeIn('slow')

  function remove_notice() {
    html.stop().fadeOut('slow').remove()
  }

  var timer =  setInterval(remove_notice, time);

  $(html).hover(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
  }, function(){
    timer = setInterval(remove_notice, time);
  });

  html.on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(timer)
    callback && callback()
    remove_notice()
  });


}

  });
```

The notification is appearing correctly because of css styling. But the script is not working. If I click close icon on notification, it's not closing. When I reload the page, it stays on the(auto closing is also not working) What ami I missing in my script?

Comment: _Script is not working_ Could you please elaborate this?

Comment: Ambiguous issue here...title says Notifications not working....last sentence says it is. Need to provide a clear, complete and understandable problem statement

Comment: The notification alert is appearing because of css. But I can't close it by clicking close icon and it stays the page.

Comment: Add that to the question

Comment: I did it. .....

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a bit difficult to understand. You refer to the "notification" appearing correctly, but the only thing I see appearing is `x Thanks` in the bottom-right corner. However, that's not a notification, it's coming from your markup. It has no event associated with it, so nothing will happen when it is clicked.

Your main issue seems to be that you are defining something called `Notify`, but then not doing anything with it.  To help you resolve this, please see  the snippet below. It's probably not exactly what you want, but I think it's a lot closer.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    Notify = function(text, callback, close_callback, style) {

        var time = '10000';
        var $container = $('#notifications');
        var icon = '<i class="fa fa-info-circle "></i>';

        if (typeof style == 'undefined' ) style = 'warning';

        var html = $('<div class="alert alert-' + style + '  hide">' + icon +  " " + text + '</div>');

        $('<a>', {
            text: '×',
            class: 'button close',
            style: 'padding-left: 10px;',
            href: '#',
            click: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                close_callback();
                remove_notice();
            }
        }).prependTo(html);

        $container.prepend(html);
        html.removeClass('hide').hide().fadeIn('slow');

        function remove_notice() {
            // html.stop().fadeOut('slow').remove()
            html.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $(this).remove(); 
            });
        }

        var timer =  setInterval(remove_notice, time);

        $(html).hover(function() {
            setMessage('You hovered over me.');
            clearInterval(timer);
        }, function(){
            if (parseInt(html.css('opacity')) === 1 ) {
                // element is not currently being faded out
                setMessage('You stopped hovering over me.');
                timer = setInterval(remove_notice, time);
            }
        });

        html.on('click', function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            callback && callback();
            remove_notice();
        });
    }

    var notification = new Notify('This is a notification.', function() {
        setMessage('You clicked my text.'); 
    }, function() {
        setMessage('You clicked my "x".'); 
    });

});

function setMessage(messageText) {
    $('#testMessage').text(messageText);
}
```

```css
#notifications {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    max-width: 300px;
}

#testMessage {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 22px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/notify/0.4.2/notify.min.js"></script>

<div id="testMessage"></div>
<div id="notifications">
<!--     <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <a class="button close" style="padding-left: 10px;" href="#">×</a>
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle "></i>
        Thanks
    </div> -->
</div>
```